# Keep android app logged in state

Tags: android, session, authentication

I have some experience in Java servlet and PHP but new to Android code. Recently I am making an Android app which can keep user logged in when the user close the app and open it again. I searched the Internet for days but still have the following questions:

1) If use SharedPreference to do this, how does the server side keep the session? Or should we store user ID on Android and skip server side authentication once user is logged in?

2) About the token, how does it work exactly? I guess it is stored in the session.  Is there any server side framework except OAuth - which I think is more suitable for third party authentication.

3) How to keep the session alive until user log out from Android? Is this a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using shared preferences or splash screen.Following are the ways

1. Using shared preference -  You make keep a boolean as userSignIn, Just make it true as soon as your OAuth is done. And once user says logout change it to false. And just check the this flag once app starts each time.
2. Using splash screen - Perform OAuth when your apps splash screen is shown to user and once request is complete move to next screen of your app.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Is there any way to skip OAuth? I plan to save an session on the server side with a long enough time out. On the Android side, I just store the session ID in the SharedPreference. What you think?

Comment: There is no concept of session in android, but yes you may store session ID. But make sure are not storing other information like password.